# FORM Action - 2 Submit Buttons email different txt files

Tags: html, css, forms, file, button

I have one form on a webpage. I would like to have 2 buttons at the bottom of the page. One to email a formatted text file if the form was completed successfully, and a separate / different text file to email if the form could NOT be completely successfully.

CSS up top -

```
<script language="javascript">
function buttonyes()
{
document............Frm.action = "http://...../cgi-bin/cgiemail.cgi/....yes.txt";   
document...........Frm.submit();        
}

function buttonno()
{
document..........Frm.action = "http://http://...../cgi-bin/cgiemail.cgi/....no.txt";
document............Frm.submit();       
}
</script>
```

Form tag.

```
<form name=" ...........Frm" method="post" id="...........Frm">
```

These are my buttons at the bottom of the page. The verify is to make sure they put their name in the name field.

```
<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="button" name="buttonyes" value="YES" style="width: 60px; height: 30px;" onclick="verify();buttonyes()" /></td>

<td align="left"><input type="button" name="buttonno" value="NO" style="width: 60px; height: 30px;" onclick="verify();buttonno()" /></td>
</tr>
```

I do not know what I should be focusing on. Additional code in the form tag, a css above, etc...

I have limited experience and was hoping someone could help out.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting bad votes but I don't know why.

Is this easier then I think and I just haven't put my finger on it ?

Is there not enough info ?